# Using binary search to retrieve duplicate elements one at a time

Tags: c, sorting, binary-search, parity

My question is: how can I retrieve duplicated elements from an array one at a time.
By one at a time I mean that this binary search is within a for loop. E.g:

```
    while (index < n){

        right_index = binarySearchfo(sorted_array, 0, n-1, original_array[index]);

        if (!checkParity(index, right_index)){
           move(original_array, sorted_array, index, n);
        }

       index++;
    }
```

My binarySearchfo function correctly returns the first occurence of the elements.

The problem is that everytime I have a duplicated element in my original_array, binarySearchfo returns the first occurrence of it in the sorted_array, but it should return the second (third and so on) depending on if it was already returned or not.

I hope it is clear.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You need to save the state, so that next call will check if the next element is a duplicate then return it, and if not then return with a failure.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that there is a better solution to your larger problem.  For example, it is entirely possible to maintain a cross-reference of which index in the sorted array corresponds to which in the original array -- this can be built during the sorting process for very little extra cost.  Then you could do away with the binary search altogether, in favor of a simple table lookup.

Comment: Once you've found the first element in the array, you can find the others by indexing until the key doesn't match any more; there's no need to search the whole array at all.  Even if you decided you did want to search the array, you could reduce the size to be scanned by not searching the part you already know about; you'd iterate on `sorted_array + last_index + 1` and reduce the size appropriately.  But the repeated search is silly; you know that the other equal entries are adjacent to the first.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I will try to do the solution you mentioned. Maybe I do not need the sorted array, but instead an array with the original indexes sorted in a way that correspond to the original array, right? I end up looking twice (sorting and binary search) to something when I only need to look once. Thank you!

Comment: @EduardoHashimoto, yes, if you don't actually need the sorted array of strings, then you do not need to produce it.  The sorted array of indexes appears to be enough to serve the purpose you present.  If you need both, then it is easy to produce them together, in the process of a single sorting process, or to produce the array of strings after the fact from the sorted array of indexes.